# Passing html form data to php isDomainAvailible function

Tags: php, html, get

I am developing a website status system, I have a html form that I use to send the data to the php script but I am having issues, my html form is a standard html form using GET.

This is my PHP

```
      <?php
        $_GET['url']=$url;// my attempt...
        if (isDomainAvailible($url))//this is where the problem is
           {
           echo "Good news! Its online and responding as it should!";
          }
          else
            {
           echo "Hmm? you sure that is a real website?";
            }

            //returns true, if domain is availible, false if not
           function isDomainAvailible($domain)
           {
           //check, if a valid url is provided
           if(!filter_var($domain, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
           {
                   return false;
           }

           //initialize curl
           $curlInit = curl_init($domain);
           curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,10);
           curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_HEADER,true);
           curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_NOBODY,true);
           curl_setopt($curlInit,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);

           //get answer
           $response = curl_exec($curlInit);

           curl_close($curlInit);

           if ($response) return true;

           return false;
   }
  ?>
```

Comment: What is the issue? You state you're having issues multiple times, but never stated what triggered you to think you had an issue?

Comment: sorry, I am not able to send the data from the form to the php script, it defaults to            echo "Hmm? you sure that is a real website?";
 because the function had no data.

Comment: shouldn't that be the other way around? `$url=$_GET['url'];` while using `isset()`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are checking the value before assigning it :

```
$url = $_GET['url'];// my attempt...
        if (isDomainAvailible($url))//this is where the problem is
           {
```

Comment: Thank you so much, that worked!